SharedTransitionTag not working - React Native, Reanimated 3, Expo 51
When try to animate shared element transition between screens using React Native SharedTransitionTag in Reanimated 3, i get very weird behaviour and not the expected animation. For me, there is no animation and when i go back, the image disappear into the top.
I'm testing it on Expo Go in my iPhone. I have tried with both Expo Router and React-Navigation NativeStack and get the same result. I have also downloaded the source code of someones course material who had it working, but when i ran it myself it did not work. The only thing i changed was bumped his Expo Go version from 49 to 51.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have any suggestions on how to fix this? My suspicion is that the issue lies with some dependencies.
Here is my code:
Screen 1
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

export default function Test() {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Test</Text>
            <Animated.Image
                source={require('./../../assets/ovelser/1-deadlift.png')}
                style={{height: 200, width: 200}}
                sharedTransitionTag="plis"
                />
            <Pressable
                onPress={() => router.push("/testend/1")}
                style={{backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10, borderRadius: 5, marginTop: 10}}
                >
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
}

Screen 2
export default function Testend() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Test</Text>
            <Animated.Image
                source={require('./../../assets/ovelser/1-deadlift.png')}
                style={{height: 400, width: 400, top: 500}}
                sharedTransitionTag="plis"
                />
        </View>
    );
}

Dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~51.0.20",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "frontend": "file:",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.74.3",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-shared-element": "^0.8.9"
  },

Also if someone has an alternative way that works. I looked into 'react-navigation-shared-element', but also failed to get it working, the package got abandoned in 2022, so i assumed it was because of that.

After some digging it seems that expo 50 and expo 51 do not support reanimated within expo go. However, people do say it works within the development build. It isn't a high priority for expo to fix.
It does work on expo 49.
You can find more information from Expo within this thread:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/27606
May they one day fix this bug.

expo 50 / expo 51 not support shared element
Currently unable to implement this feature.
